# How to change toolbar icon color programmatically and theme way?

Tags: android

How to change toolbar icon color programmatically and theme way?
Please suggest the best way to change the color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Programmatically you can change color like below

```
Drawable drawable = toolbar.getNavigationIcon();
drawable.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(appCompatActivity, colorId), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Also, you can change this through the theme.

```
<style name="ToolbarColoreTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">INSERT_COLOR_HERE</item>
</style>
```

apply the above theme in your toolbar like below

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        ***app:theme="@style/ToolbarColoreTheme"***
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
```